# The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine. After migrating from ASP.Net RC1 to RC2.Error with Access Database:

Tags: provider, .net-core-rc2

Before migration towards RC2 my code was working very fine. Here is my code for connecting with Access Database:

```
public OleDbConnection getDbConnection()
        {
            OleDbConnection returnValue = null;
            try
            {
                returnValue = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
                returnValue.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ErrorMessage = "Error Occured While Opening Database Connection." + ex.Message + " " + ex.InnerException;                
            }
            return returnValue;
        }
```

Same code is using for SQL and working fine but for Access it is showing me this error: The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine
I have tried these solution: [1](http://www.connectionstrings.com/the-microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine/) and [2](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/417397/OLEDB-Provider-is-Not-Registered-on-the-Local-Mach) but no success.

Comment: I have confirmed, this is an issue of RC2. Any solution for RC2 to connect with mdb files using OleDb

Comment: Were you able to fix this? I am having the same issue.

Comment: Could not able to resolve

Comment: I fixed it finally check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue by

1. uninstalling Microsoft Access database engine 2010 32 bit version
2. uninstalling 2007 Office System Driver: Data Connectivity Components 32bit version
3. Installing Microsoft Access database engine 2010 64 bit version
4. In IIS App Pool for the project Set Enable 32bit apps to false